# Which is the best load testing tool for serverless architecture?

Tags: performance-testing

Anything otherthan Jmeter tool

Answer (score 1):

In absolute majority of cases you don't need to test the serverless application itself as it is being run by 3rd-party provider, i.e. [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) or [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)

The only thing it makes sense to do is to perform analysis of the "function" implementation in order to identify that it is well developed from code perspective:

- uses [optimal algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
- doesn't have obvious [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- uses underlying infrastructure efficiently from [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)) perspectice

All this can be done using source code analysis and [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))

---

If your question is broader and you're looking for a load testing tool other than JMeter - check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article which describes alternatives including but not limited to:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

However "classic" load testing tools are not applicable to [FAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_service) applications

Comment: The main thing I am looking is Concurrent request execution. Something like postman + cocncurrency